Issue with Ubuntu 24.04.01 on Dual Boot: Laptop Shuts Down Unexpectedly
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04.01 in dual boot with Windows 12 on my laptop with the following specs:
•   HP Pavilion Gaming
•   Intel i5 11th Gen
•   NVIDIA RTX 3050
•   16 GB RAM

The problem only occurs when running Ubuntu. After shutting down, the laptop powers on but only the power button lights up briefly before it turns off again. Sometimes it works fine for about 30 minutes to an hour, but then the issue reappears.
Has anyone experienced this, or does anyone have suggestions for a fix? I’d appreciate any help!
